# Give a status code 404 response for unmatched routes with React and React Router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, https, react-router, seo

So I know how to handle unmatched routes with React Router:

```js
<Routes>
    {/* Public routes */}
    <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />

    // Rest of my routes...

    {/* Error routes */}
    <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
</Routes>
```

But how would I handle the header status code response? Because this way every response is a `200`, which of course makes sense. I understand that's a server response, but how would I go about asking my backend dev to handle these routes so the response **status code is `404`**? Is there any way to do it from my side using React Router? Like intercepting the response and changing the status or something similar?

Is the only way to achieve this via the server side? And if it is, what would I need to do? Roughly, I just want to know what to ask from the backend guys.

All of this is because of SEO, Google says showing a "not found" page and responding with `200` is a bad practice.

Comment: You can do this via

Server-side rendering (SSR): Implementing SSR allows the server to render the initial HTML of your application, including the correct status code based on the requested route. This way, search engines will see the appropriate status codes.

OR

Dynamic server-side routing: Instead of relying solely on React Router for client-side routing, you can configure your server to handle routing and return the correct status code based on the requested route. This approach requires server-side code changes to handle the routing logic and return the appropriate status codes.

Answer (score 0):

The http status code can only be set from the server, in response to a request from the browser. This is something that can only be done from the back-end. With a nodejs server for example (https://expressjs.com/en/starter/faq.html)

```
app.use((request, response) => {
  response.status(404).send("Page not found");
})
```